# Strange javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I have found the following regular expression

```
new RegExp("(^|\\s)hello(\\s|$)");
```

I refer http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml for regular expressions..
But i cannot see \s escape sequence there..I know \s indicate whitespace character...
But what  does the preceding \ do ..Which character is escaped?
I found similar regular expression in the Treewalker code in the following document http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Comment: `\\` is an escaped slash, translating to `\`. If you want spaces, you should be using `\s`, with a single slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double `\\` is to escape the backslash inside the string. In other word, `\\` will be interpreted as `\` for the regular expression.

Comment: ok simple \ is treated as escape in string sowe need two slashes right?

Comment: Exactly, the code need to escape the backslash in order for the regex to treat it as a single backslash which will alows it to get `\s` as a whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

The extra \ in this case is to escape the \ in the \s.  Because we are inside a string declaration, you have to double up the \ to escape it.  Once the string is processed and saved, it is reduced down to (^|\s)hello(\s|$)

Answer (score 1):

The character immediately following the first `\` is escaped. Normally `\s` escapes the `s` to mean "whitespace". In your example, the character which is escaped is `\`.

What you have is an expression which builds a regex (presumably to pass elsewhere) of `(^|\s)hello(\s|$)` — the word "hello" preceded either by whitespace or the start of the string, and followed by whitespace or the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what the reg ex is doing, is looking for the opening and closing items of text surrounding the word hello and literally interpreting the '\s' as string content at the same time.

In laymans terms it's looking for a string that exactly matches:

|\shello\s|

As others have said the double \ is to escape the single \ so that instead of the reg ex engine looking for white-space it actually looks for '\s' as a string.

The ^ means start of line, the $ means end of line and the 2 | are interpreted as actual chars to look for

Lastly your start and end markers are bracketed () which means they will be extracted and placed in matches, which for you using C# means you can get at them by using:

```
myRegex.Matches.Group[1].Value
myRegex.Matches.Group[2].Value
```

1 being the beginning grouping, and 2 being the end.